# How to Display Limit Content When Content has Html Tag

Tags: php, jquery, css, laravel-5

Hello I have a content

Sail under the iconic Tower Bridge and enjoy spectacular river views of **London’s most famous landmarks** with the **MBNA Thames Clippers.** Select from a choice of **three different ticket options.** With freedom to **hop on and off** at any of the **17 piers** in the **Central and East Zones,** the **River Roamer Ticket** is ideal for a day of sightseeing in London. **Single and return tickets** are also available to purchase, perfect for travelling in comfort and style from A to B.

I want to apply **Read more** I am using like

```
@if(strlen($products_data->longDesc)>1000)
    {!! nl2br(substr($products_data->longDesc,0,100)) !!}
    <span class="moreellipses" style="display: inline;">...&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="more-text" style="display: none;">{!! nl2br(substr($products_data->longDesc,100)) !!}</span>
    <a class="read_more_text" href="javascript:void(0)">Read more</a>
    <a class="read_less_text hide" href="javascript:void(0)">Read less</a>
@else
    {!! nl2br($products_data->longDesc) !!}
@endif
```

But some time i am facing issue with this function   **substr($products_data->longDesc,0,100)**   it give me string without close tag like <stro  and then my site layout create problem how to manage read more with html tag

Answer (score 0):

use css **-webkit-line-clamp** property
More description follow https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/